# gcloud: how to download the app via cli

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, gcloud

I depolyed an app with gcloud preview app deploy.

Is there a way to download it to an other local machine?
How can I get the files? I tried it via ssh with no success (can't access the docker dir)

UPDATE:
I found this:

```
gcloud preview app modules download default --version 1 --output-dir=my_dir
```

but it's not loading files

Log

```
Downloading module [default] to [my_dir/default]
Fetching file list from server...
|- Downloading [0] files...                                 -|
```

Comment: `gcloud preview app modules download` is an artifact of the old-style AppEngine (i.e. not with Docker). It won't work with Docker-style apps. (We have that functionality coming, but while `gcloud app` is in preview mode, things will be spotty).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently, the best way to do this is to pull the files out of Docker.

Put instance into self-managed mode, so that you can ssh into it:

```
$ gcloud preview app modules set-managed-by default --version 1 --self
```

Find the name of the instance:

```
$ gcloud compute instances list | grep gae-default-1
```

Copy it out of the Docker container, change the permissions, and copy it back to your local machine:

```
$ gcloud compute ssh --zone=us-central1-f gae-default-1-1234 'sudo docker cp gaeapp:/app /tmp'
$ gcloud compute ssh --zone=us-central1-f gae-default-1-1234 "chown -R $USER /tmp/app"
$ gcloud compute copy-files --zone=us-central1-f gae-default-1-1234:/tmp/app /tmp/
$ ls /tmp/app
Dockerfile
[...]
```

Comment: Thanks for your help Zachary!
I'm getting a ssh timeout :(


gcloud compute ssh --zone=us-central1-c gae-default-1-g5ol 'sudo docker cp gaeapp:/app /tmp'
ssh: connect to host 104.154.73.30 port 22: Operation timed out
ERROR: (gcloud.compute.ssh) [/usr/bin/ssh] exited with return code [255]. See https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/troubleshooting#ssherrors for troubleshooting hints.

Comment: What happens if you try the same thing from the [Cloud Console](https://cloud.google.com/console) (Compute > AppEngine > Instances, then find the name of an instance running the version of the app you want and hit SSH)?

Comment: The first command doesn't seem to be a valid command any more.

Answer (score 18):

I am coming to Google App Engine after two years, I see that they have made lots of improvements and added tons of features. But sadly, their documentation sometimes leaves much to be desired.

I used to download my code of the uploaded version with the `appcfg.py`using the following command.

`appcfg.py download_app -A <app_id> -V <version> <output-dir>`

But of course now that they have culminated everything in the gcloud shell where `appcfg.py` is not accessible.

However, the following method helped me to download the deployed code:

1. Go the console and in to the Google App Engine.
2. Select the project you want to work with.
3. Once the project's dashboard opens, Click on the top right to
   open the built in console window.

   [image]
4. Which should load the cloud shell at the bottom, now if you check `appcfg.py` is available to you to use in this VM.

   [image: enter imagedescription her[2]]
5. Hence, use `appcfg.py download_app -A <app_id> -V <version> <output-dir>` to download the code.
6. Now once you have the code in the desired folder, in order to download it on your local machine - You can open the docker code editor

   [image]
7. Now here I assumed if I rightclicked and exported the desired
   folder it would work,

   [image]

   but instead it gave me the following error message.

   ```
   {"Error":"'concurrency' must be a number but it is [object Undefined]","Message":"'concurrency' must be a number but it is [object Undefined]"}
   ```
8. So, I thought maybe it would play along nicely if the the folder
   was an archive. Go back to the cloud shell and using whatever
   utility you fancy make an archive of the folder

   ```
   zip -r mycode.zip mycode
   ```
9. Go to the docker code editor, export and download.

   [image]

Now. Of course there might many more ways do it (hopefully) but this is what made sense to me after returning to Google App Engine after 2 years.

Comment: Coming to this a year later after this was posted and this is the only method that worked for me.
Thank you!

Comment: I don't see the output_dir getting created anywhere

Answer (score 2):

IMHO, the best option today (Aug 2018) is:

Under the main menu, under Products, go to `Tools -> Cloud Build -> Build history`.

There, click the ID of the build you want.

Then, in the opened window (Build details), click the `source` link, the download of your compressed code begins.

As simple as that.

HTH.

Comment: I can follow up to "clidk the ID" but I do not see a source link in there.

Answer (score 0):

As of Feb 2021, you can install appengine-sdk using pip

`pip install appengine-sdk`

Once installed, appcfg can be used to download the app code.

`python -m appcfg download_app -A app_id [ -V version ] out-dir`

Answer (score 0):

Nothing works. Finally I found the source code this way. Simply go to google cloud storage. choose buckets starting with us.artifacts...., select containers > images > download the latest one (look by created date). unzip after downloaded file. it will have all the deployed source code of app engine.