# Where are my application files after deploy to google compute engine?

Tags: ruby, google-compute-engine, gcloud

I'm following the [tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/ruby/getting-started/hello-world) to deploy a ruby app to google compute engine. Everything works, however I now want to ssh into the app to run migrations etc. After some searching i was able to find my files under a docker instance here `/var/lib/docker/aufs/diff/e2972171505a931749490e13d21e4f8c0bb076245ef4b592aff6667c45b2dd13/app`

Is there a simpler way to access my files? perhaps a symlinked folder?

Comment: possible duplicate of [gcloud: how to download the app via cli](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32487781/gcloud-how-to-download-the-app-via-cli)

Answer (score 0):

Ruby apps on Google AppEngine run via Docker. Because AppEngine is a PaaS provider, it's discouraged (though possible) to run commands on production machines. If you'd like to run database migrations, please run them locally and point your configuration at your production database.