# Error while downloading source code from App Engine

Tags: python, laravel, google-app-engine

For now 2 days, i'm trying to download the source code from one of my project deployed on a Google App Engine to patch a important bug on a Laravel based website... Unhopefully the command who allow a user to download his source code is deprecated (`appcfg.py`).

But according to the GCP support and a recent post of StackOverflow, this command stay available until 2020, when i'm trying to download the files (over 7k of files) i'm getting an error message after only 23 files downloaded...

According to the GCP doc, the command is :

```
appcfg.py -A axial-yen-****** -V *************** download_app C:\******
```

The error code:

```
Error 500: --- begin server output ---
<ApiError 500, Message: "com.google.net.rpc3.util.RpcFutureStream$RpcStreamException: <eye3 title='/Tidepool.ReadContent2, UNKNOWN'/> ZERO_APP::0: invalid argument
        Suppressed: CriticalInputFailure: com.google.apphosting.admin.zeus.files.FileContentsProducerModule$TitaniumUncheckedFileContentsProducerModule.produceTitaniumFileContents failed while trying to inject @com.google.apps.framework.producers.PrivateVisibility(module=com.google.apphosting.admin.zeus.files.FileContentsProducerModule$TitaniumUncheckedFileContentsProducerModule.class) com.google.common.collect.ImmutableList<com.google.apphosting.riptide.TidepoolPb$ReadContentReply>
        Suppressed: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:
">
--- end server output --
```

I'd like to understand where the matters come from or if there are an another way to get all of there files down on my computer :-) ...
Thanks you in advance. Echo

Answer (score 0):

Based on the documentation from Google App Engine, the command that you are using [is now deprecated](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/tools/downloading-source-code).

The recommended alternative for this deprecated feature is [migrate to gcloud command line](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/sdk-gcloud-migration).

Hope this helps you!

Comment: Hello thanks for your answer but, unhopefully, there a no such commands that allow to download his source code from an app engine. This command too is no longer working https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32487781/gcloud-how-to-download-the-app-via-cli

Answer (score 0):

As @eespinola mentioned, the appcfg.app command is [deprecated](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/tools/downloading-source-code). However, you should be able to use it until [July 30, 2020](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/sdk-gcloud-migration).

The documentation from the [Cloud SDK for Python 2](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/download#appengine_sdk) (the one that has the "appcfg.py" tool) shows that only supports: python 2.7, Java 8, PHP 5, Go 1.9.

I reproduce the error while trying to download an application in Python 3.7 (not supported) but was able to download successfully an application in Python 2.7 (supported).

I'm assuming your application version uses a PHP higher than PHP 5 and that's why is failing.

I understand that you would want an updated version of this functionality for the **gcloud** command, since the "appcfg.py" is not longer being supported. Please refer to this [feature tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/138601958) to follow the updates of this feature for **gcloud** command, click the star at the left to subscribe to it an receive future updates.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer. Unfortunately, the files that i'm trying to download are inclueded inside Laravel, and for what i saw there's no folder/file with any special characters in its name... Echo.

Comment: I see, by any chance are you trying to download a version that is currently serving traffic?. Also, could you edit your question and add the full logs you get from the console when running the command? (redact it in case it has sensitive information)

Comment: Hey, yep i'm trying to download the version that is currently serving traffic. I'm running the command from the windows shell (from the appcfg.py folder).

Comment: I think that might be the issue. Is failing because it cannot download a file that is currently in use.

Comment: So, i've disable the application, and tried again, the result was the same. error 500

Comment: when you say you "disable the application" you mean that you have stopped the version that were serving? Did you wait a few minutes before running the command ? (sometimes it can take a few seconds to stop the instances). Which "Google Cloud SDK" and "app-engine-python" versions are you using? (you can see this by running the command: "gcloud -v" )

Comment: Hey, i can't stop the version from the version page. I would say i've disabled it from the settings page. I've tried to wait few minutes before trying to download the files but i get the same error as before. https://imgur.com/wMzn09Y

Comment: Hi Echo_Alex, I have updated my answer with the new information i gather, please take a look.