# Download Nodejs project from AppEngine

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I have recently lost access to my hard drive ( it died) and the only source code of my application ( Node JS) is at the Google Cloud Platform. Is there a way that i can download my node js project from the GCP? i google it up, and notice the download function only available at Python

Comment: I assume you aren't using Cloud Source Repos or any other Git-like option? In the future, use version-control. Or at least Dropbox/Drive syncing

Comment: In any case, it is not clear where your project is deployed to... I believe there is a way to download AppEngine applications. You could SCP to an GCE node (unless you lost the SSH key as well)

Comment: @cricket_007 yes.. does it mean theres's no way on getting it back?.. my project deployed to the app engine. as per the guide here https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/nodejs/runtime

Comment: you can find my article here, use winscp to download files from google cloud: https://medium.com/google-cloud/set-up-anaconda-under-google-cloud-vm-on-windows-f71fc1064bd7

Comment: @Raymond but im using the App engine. that article refer to the Compute Engine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, hard lesson learned - Use [Cloud Source Repos](https://cloud.google.com/source-repositories/), and [hook up functions such that a commit there will (re)deploy your AppEngine service(s)](https://cloud.google.com/source-repositories/docs/quickstart-triggering-builds-with-source-repositories). Basically, preventing you from needing to download any dpeloyment tools locally, and removing the possibility of losing code (unless GCP is unavailable).

---

I think I've done it in the past with Python apps, but at the moment, I found this if you have a Flexible instance of AppEngine

> `gcloud app instances scp` lets you remotely copy files to or from an App Engine Flexible instance`

https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/app/instances/scp

Basically, I don't think the UI will let you get your code, but `gcloud app` probably has more functionality.

And I am also not seeing anything specific for Node, but the best workaround I can think of would be to try to SSH to the machine, if you can, then SCP should work as well to pull files off it.

Comment: im having issue on the mentioning the destination, is this correct?

gcloud app instances scp --services=default --version=v5 --C:\Users\Me

Comment: That is the start of the command. I don't know the instances running in your project to give you more than that

Comment: In any case, this command will not work in the Standard AppEngine instance (which is offered as part of a Node project)

Comment: Realistically, you could contact GCP support, and they could probably email you your code, or put it in a GCS location for you

Comment: i see. ok will try to find the contact button.

Comment: oh i browsed the contact support, and they bring me here.. to the community support :(

Comment: They also link here https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/google-appengine

Answer (score 2):

Found an answer. This guy already solve it. Many thanks on the comments :)

[gcloud: how to download the app via cli](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32487781/gcloud-how-to-download-the-app-via-cli)

Comment: Please accept your own answer in order to set as the good one.

Comment: After half way through the post, i still failed to download the code. So its not a good answer :(